# How can you stop the screen scrolling from the top of a Phonegap app?

Tags: css, cordova, scroll, zepto

I'm currently using Phonegap to develop. It works fine, except there's a small (~1 pixel) bar along the top, touching which will cause the entire application to scroll, which I don't want. Here's what I'm using to prevent the rest of the app from scrolling:

```
<div id="container" ontouchstart="stopIt(event, true);" ontouchmove="stopIt(event, true);" ontouchend="stopIt(event, false);">

stopIt = function(event, touching)
{
    event.preventDefailt();
    //Other code
}
```

And the CSS:

```
#container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this, or how to fix it?

Comment: Can you show an image/example?

Comment: Not easily. It's just this one pixel height row at the top of the page, and touching it causes everything to scroll, when it shouldn't. What do you want an image of?

Comment: I don't understand, why do you have this 1 pixel bar there if it's causing problems?

Comment: Sorry, I guess it's kind of confusing. I didn't put it in, the top row of pixels will cause the app to scroll if it's touched. There's no real "bar", it's just the very top of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're talking about the status bar on the top of an iPhone? Yes that will always scroll to the top, and there is no way to catch this event and stop it from the browser.

You'll need to set the web view's scrollToTop attribute as false from the native side. That should work.

```
[theWebView setScrollsToTop:NO];
```

Comment: No, I'm not. Sorry, but it's happening on the Playbook, too, which doesn't have a status bar.